# How to get inserted image in a received gmail mail

Tags: image, google-apps-script, gmail

I want to get the inserted image (not image attachment) in a received Gmail mail. How is this done using Google Apps Script?

I have tried to use `urlfetchapp` to get the image data from the image link address:

> https//mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?ui=2&ik=c348ccba97&view=att&th=13bb892c352c45dc&attid=0.2&disp=emb&realattid=ii_13bb88f3e56aae8c&zw&atsh=1

in the email html body, but can not bypass the google login page. The response content data always is login page.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit**: While the code below works on email drafts and canned responses, it does not let you access inline images in ***received*** email.

This code snippet is from a working mail merge I have that supports inline images (both embedded blobs and external references) and attachments as well. It takes the inline images and attachments from a draft/canned response, adds them to a new email and sends it:

```
...
//selectedTemplate is a Gmail Message (draft/canned response) 
var emailTemplate = selectedTemplate.getBody(); 
var attachments = selectedTemplate.getAttachments();

if(emailTemplate.search(/<\img/ != -1)){  
    var inlineImages = {};
    var imgVars = emailTemplate.match(/<img[^>]+>/g);
    for(i in imgVars){
      var title = imgVars[i].match(/title="([^\"]+\")/);
      if (title) {
        title = title[1].substr(0, title[1].length-1);
        var titleEncoded = title.replace(/ /g,"-");
        for(j in attachments){
          if(attachments[j].getName() == title){
            inlineImages[titleEncoded] = attachments[j].copyBlob().setName(titleEncoded);
            attachments.splice(j,1);
          }
        }
        var newImg = imgVars[i].replace(/src="[^\"]+\"/,"src=\"cid:"+titleEncoded+"\"");
        emailTemplate = emailTemplate.replace(imgVars[i],newImg);
      }
    }
  }
...
GmailApp.sendEmail("test@example.com", "my subject", "my body",
                  {attachments: attachments,
                   inlineImages: inlineImages});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have tried it, but in my side, for inlineImage in gmail message, there is not attachment related to it, so your solution can not work for me.

Comment: Happy to help debug this or confirm for you. If you'd like to, please send one of your test emails to me (see my profile).

Comment: hi Peter, I can not find your mail address in this profile. I want to send my test mail to you. Could you give me your mail address?

Comment: I have sent my test mail to you. pls help to analysis the inline image issue. Thanks

Comment: Wow, you're correct, this does not pick up inline images from received email. Like normal attachments, I would have expected the inline images to be accessible without having to parse the raw mime. I would log an issue. [Issue 1965](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1965) is related but I suggest you log a new one for specifically the use case you want. Sorry I wasn't able to solve this for you. BTW, you might want to try your UrlFetch method but use an OAuth header.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you are accessing your emails, but it doesn't look like you are using the [GmailApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_gmailapp) from the Gmail service. Once you've found the email you're interested in then examine the html body to find the `<img>`. Either `src` will be a url (linked image) or a cid (embedded image) that references an attachment.

Comment: Yes, I can find the image link in email body, but how to get the image data? I want to download the image using app-script. I tried use UrlFetchApp.fetch to get the image content, but because this link need  google access authority, so the return response is always the google login page, how to bypass it to get real image content data.

Comment: Ah - inline images aren't accessible via getAttachments. Also, I made a misunderstanding, the cid bit is for the sending side, once received it will be a google url. It looks like someone else has had this problem, see [issue 1659](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1659), also a possible workaround.

Answer (score 0):

A more recent approach to solving this.

The issue

For example, here's an email body retrieved with .getBody()

```
<div dir="ltr"><div><img src="?view=att&amp;th=1401f70d4881e07f&amp;attid=0.3&amp;disp=emb&amp;realattid=ii_1401f6fc7824ebe1&amp;zw&amp;atsh=1" alt="Inline image 4" width="200" height="180"><br></div><div><br></div><img src="?view=att&amp;th=1401f70d4881e07f&amp;attid=0.2&amp;disp=emb&amp;realattid=ii_1401f6e6c1d46c4b&amp;zw&amp;atsh=1" alt="Inline image 2" width="200" height="65"><div><br></div><div>
jtykuykyu</div><div><br></div><div><img src="?view=att&amp;th=1401f70d4881e07f&amp;attid=0.1&amp;disp=emb&amp;realattid=ii_1401f6e9df3a4b1c&amp;zw&amp;atsh=1" alt="Inline image 3" width="200" height="82"><br><div><br></div><div><br></div></div></div>
```

And here is the list of attachments for the email (among which are our inline images):

[13-07-30 08:28:08:378 CEST] Screen Shot 2013-07-12 at 1.54.31 PM.png

[13-07-30 08:28:08:379 CEST] Screen Shot 2013-07-23 at 5.38.51 PM.png

[13-07-30 08:28:08:380 CEST] Screen Shot 2013-07-25 at 9.05.15 AM.png

[13-07-30 08:28:08:381 CEST] test2.png

As you can see, there's no link between the name of those images and the information available in the img tags, so there's no safe way to rebuild a correct email with only those information.

The solution

How to solve that ? We can use the method .getRawContent() to get the actual email and parse it to get the information we need. Specifically, this method give us a relationship between the name of an attachment and the 'realattid' available in the email body:

Content-Type: image/png; name="Screen Shot 2013-07-25 at 9.05.15 AM.png"

Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

Content-ID:

X-Attachment-Id: ii_1401f6e9df3a4b1c

Code snippet

Here's a code snippet to:

-Retrieve the body & attachments of an email

-Get all the img tags inside the body and see which ones are linked to attachments in the email

-Get the 'realattid' of each image and use .getRawContent() to link this 'realattid' to the right attachment

-Replace the img tag to correctly link it to the right attachment

-Indicate that this attachment is no longer a simple attachment but an inline image

-Once all that is done you have all  the data you need to send a copy of this email with the correct inline images displayed.

```
 //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // Get inline images and make sure they stay as inline images
  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  var emailTemplate = selectedTemplate.getBody();
  var rawContent = selectedTemplate.getRawContent();
  var attachments = selectedTemplate.getAttachments();

  var regMessageId = new RegExp(selectedTemplate.getId(), "g");
  if (emailTemplate.match(regMessageId) != null) {
    var inlineImages = {};
    var nbrOfImg = emailTemplate.match(regMessageId).length;
    var imgVars = emailTemplate.match(/<img[^>]+>/g);
    var imgToReplace = [];
    if(imgVars != null){
      for (var i = 0; i < imgVars.length; i++) {
        if (imgVars[i].search(regMessageId) != -1) {
          var id = imgVars[i].match(/realattid=([^&]+)&/);
          if (id != null) {
            var temp = rawContent.split(id[1])[1];
            temp = temp.substr(temp.lastIndexOf('Content-Type'));
            var imgTitle = temp.match(/name="([^"]+)"/);
            if (imgTitle != null) imgToReplace.push([imgTitle[1], imgVars[i], id[1]]);
          }
        }
      }
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < imgToReplace.length; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < attachments.length; j++) {
        if(attachments[j].getName() == imgToReplace[i][0]) {
          inlineImages[imgToReplace[i][2]] = attachments[j].copyBlob();
          attachments.splice(j, 1);
          var newImg = imgToReplace[i][1].replace(/src="[^\"]+\"/, "src=\"cid:" + imgToReplace[i][2] + "\"");
          emailTemplate = emailTemplate.replace(imgToReplace[i][1], newImg);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  var message = {
    htmlBody: emailTemplate,
    subject: selectedTemplate.getSubject(),
    attachments: attachments,
    inlineImages: inlineImages
  }
```